# Use Ethernet only for Wireshark when WiFi is enabled (Linux)

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, wireshark

I'm using Wireshark to capture network traffic (via a SharkTap 10/100.) This works well but when I plug in the Ethernet cable the laptop treats it as a normal LAN connection and routes all laptop traffic over Ethernet. I would prefer that it use Ethernet only for packet capture and continue to use WiFi for all (other) traffic.

I suppose there is a way to do this but it is beyond my chops as a network engineer. ;)

Without the Ethernet connected 'route' reports:

```
hbarta@yggdrasil ~ $ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         router.asus.com 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
172.16.86.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
192.168.85.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
```

with Ethernet plugged in I see

```
hbarta@yggdrasil ~ $ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.31.1.254     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.31.1.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
172.16.86.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
192.168.85.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
```

I am running Linux Mint (an Ubuntu/Debian derivative)

Thanks!

Edit: The VMWARE routes are there because I have VMWARE installed. I do not have (or need to have) any VMs running while I'm doing this.

Comment: After connecting a SharkTap to your Linux machine, can you add a route manually on this VM machine pointing the correct gateway IP?

Comment: The VMWARE routes are there because I have VMWARE installed. I do not have (or need to have) any VMs running while I'm doing this.

Comment: The answer is to change the default route back out the wlan0 interface.  (Can't advise how to do this automatically on mint - on Ubuntu you can "Edit Connections" and set the Ethernet interface (IPv4) as Automatic (DHCP) addresses only. - I think.   I do everything from /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: Thanks for the tip, davidgo. I went into "edit connections" (right click on the network icon in the system tray), click on Wired Connection 1, click edit and in the General tab and uncheck the "Automatically connect to this network when it is available."

When I do that and plug in the Ethernet cable, routing remains on the WiFi network and Wireshark has access to Ethernet. There's probably a command line or config file equivalent but this works easily enough.

Thanks!